# MySQL query question

Tags: mysql

I have a list of categories ordered alphabetically but I want to be able to specify a single category to be included last is it possible to do this with MySQL?

for example

current output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

desired output:

```
b
c
d
e
f
g
a
```

Current MySQL code.

```
 SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, category ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that `'a' = 'a'` returns 1 and `'a' = 'b'` returns 0:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, category = 'a', category
```

Comment: is there a way I can select a certain word from a category?